# Expandable listview without Child Item

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using expandable listview where I am creating an app the problem is when a parent has no child is selected the app is crash with null pointer exception (like from my code it's first and last list header all other header has the child in it that on selection move towards their fragment). how to deal with this problem??

Thank you in advance below is my sample code:

**code from main activity**

```
expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            v.setSelected(true);
            switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:
                            fragment = new PrimerFragment();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            fragment = new SettingTabFragment();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                    case 2:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:
                            fragment = new TabFragment();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            fragment = new CreamTabFragment();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            fragment = new FoundationFragment();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    finish();
                    break;
                default:
                    fragment=new HomeFragment();
                    break;
            }

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expandableList);
            return false;
        }
    });
}


  listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    listDataHeader = Arrays.asList(array);

    // setting essentials

    List<String> setting = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] set = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.setting);
    setting = Arrays.asList(set);

    // foundation essentials

    List<String> foundation = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] found = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.foundation);
    foundation = Arrays.asList(found);

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), new ArrayList<String>()); 
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), setting);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), foundation);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

**Expandable list view adapter code**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
                             List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(
            this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.listItems);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(
            this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.listheader);
    // lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    return convertView;
}
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know where the null pointer exception is thrown?

Maybe here:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(
            this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}
```

you are calling .size() in a null reference. Have you tried?

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if (this._listDataChild.get(
               this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)) == null) {
       return 0;

    } else {
       return this._listDataChild.get(
            this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution above not crash the app. But when I click on the home it does not move towards the home fragment.

Comment: Maybe you have to do expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(...) in activity like the expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(...) you have but considering in the swith/case only the positions for parents that you know have no child.